# Dataframe to Json to D3 via Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, d3.js

I'm currently building a flask webapp and trying to create a d3 chart. D3 takes json as the data input, so I converted my dataframe to json in the following way:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'Name':  ['JOHN DOE', 'APPLE INC', 'MIKE LOWRY'],
        'Value': ['10', '20','30']})

df_json_output = df.to_json()
```

Then after taking [the sample d3 treemap code](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/treemap_json.html) on the d3 website I just changed the data source

From:

```
// read json data
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_dendrogram_full.json", function(data) {
```

to

```
// read json data
d3.json({{ df_json_putput }}, function(data) {
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:
[image]

[image]

My hunch is that the script is only meant to take a link to a json file, not the actual values? Is it possible to do without a link? But actually just feed it the json values?

Full script:

```
    <script>

                                // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
                                var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
                                  width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
                                  height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                                
                                // append the svg object to the body of the page
                                var svg = d3.select("#treemap")
                                .append("svg")
                                  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                                  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                                .append("g")
                                  .attr("transform",
                                        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                                
                                // read json data
                                d3.json({{ df_json_output  }}, function(data) {
                                
                                  // Give the data to this cluster layout:
                                  var root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(function(d){ return d.value}) // Here the size of each leave is given in the 'value' field in input data
                                
                                  // Then d3.treemap computes the position of each element of the hierarchy
                                  d3.treemap()
                                    .size([width, height])
                                    .padding(2)
                                    (root)
                                
                                  // use this information to add rectangles:
                                  svg
                                    .selectAll("rect")
                                    .data(root.leaves())
                                    .enter()
                                    .append("rect")
                                      .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x0; })
                                      .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y0; })
                                      .attr('width', function (d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
                                      .attr('height', function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
                                      .style("stroke", "black")
                                      .style("fill", "slateblue")
                                
                                  // and to add the text labels
                                  svg
                                    .selectAll("text")
                                    .data(root.leaves())
                                    .enter()
                                    .append("text")
                                      .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x0+5})    // +10 to adjust position (more right)
                                      .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y0+20})    // +20 to adjust position (lower)
                                      .text(function(d){ return d.data.name })
                                      .attr("font-size", "15px")
                                      .attr("fill", "white")
                                })
                                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [`d3.json`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#json) is only meant to read the json file. Try directly setting the variable data to the value you have returned from python. To prevent the unexpected token error, use the [`tojson`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters) in jinja2 so javascript would recognize the JSON correctly.

```js
let data = {{ df_json_putput|tojson }};
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a JSON object instead of a file just change

```
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_dendrogram_full.json", function(data) {

// do something

}
```

to

```
  let data = myJSonVariable; // in your case: data = {{ df_json_putput }};
  // do something
```